# Why am I getting a List index is out of range?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to construct a program that will output a senators name for each input of a number giving by a user up to and including 31. I have a list of Senators each belonging to a specific number and when a user inputs a number the result is the corresponding Senator name.
When I run the program, however, I keep getting an error message

```
"Index Error: List index out of range".
```

What am I doing wrong? Here is the code:

```
def main():
    senators = ['Kevin Eltife', 'Bob Deuell','Robert Nichols', 'Tommy Williams',
                'Charles Schwertner', 'Sylvia Garcia', 'Dan Patrick', 'Ken Paxton',
                'Kelly Hancock', 'Wendy Davis', 'Larry Taylor', 'Jane Nelson',
                'Rodney Ellis', 'Kirk Watson', 'John Whitmire', 'John Carona',
                'Joan Huffman', 'Glenn Hegar', 'Carlos Uresti', 'Juan "Chuy" Hinojosa',
                'Judith Zaffirini', 'Brian Birdwell', 'Royce West', 'Troy Fraser',
                'Donna Campbell', 'Leticia Van de Putte', 'Eddie Lucio, Jr.',
                'Robert Cuncan', 'Jose Rodriguez', 'Craig Estes', 'Kel Seliger']

    district_number = int(input('Give the senator''s district number (enter 0 to end): '))
    while district_number > len(senators):
        print('That district number does not occur in Texas.')
        district_number = int(input('Enter another valid district number (enter 0 to quit): '))

    while district_number != 0:
        print('That district is served by the honorable ', senators[district_number - 1], '.', sep='')
        district_number = int(input('Enter another district number (enter 0 to quit): '))

# Call the main function.
main()
```

Please help...thank you. =)

Comment: Format your code properly

Comment: `while district_number >= len(senators):` replaces `while district_number > len(senators):`

Comment: what is the value of `district_number` when you the get the index error.

Comment: On what input does it give you an index out of bounds error?

Comment: @GamesBrainiac When I enter 34 it gives me the error. It gives me the error the second time I enter the number.

Comment: @FredRamirez Does my answer work for you then?

Answer (score 2):

Once you get a first input less than 31, you enter a loop where you no longer check for maximum district number. So a sequence say 20 then 40 will cause an index error.

Answer (score 1):

First off, I'd suggest not using a list. If you use a dictionary you can employ the get() method and simply check if it returned a result or not. While I'm no professional, this seems to me to be a best practice. Here's an example.

```
SENATORS = {1: 'Kevin Eltife', 
            2: 'Bob Deuell',
            3: 'Robert Nichols', 
            4: 'Tommy Williams',
            5: 'Charles Schwertner', 
            6: 'Sylvia Garcia', 
            7: 'Dan Patrick'}

while True: # loop until program is exited
  district_number = int(input('Give the senator''s district number (enter 0 to end): '))
  senator = SENATORS.get(district_number) # Will return None if user enters invalid number
  if senator:
    print('That district is served by the honorable ', senator, '.', sep='')
  else:
    print('That district number does not occur in Texas.')
```

In my opinion this is not only easier to read, but will be easier to edit in the future should you need to, and eliminates user error (Unless they of course type "duck" or "baseball", in which case your int() call will get very angry.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you're using an index number directly:

```
print('That district is served by the honorable ', senators[district_number - 1], '.', sep='')
```

You should put this around a `try/except` block:

```
while district_number != 0:
    try:
        print('That district is served by the honorable ', senators[district_number - 1], '.', sep='')
    except IndexError:
        print("District Number too high")
    district_number = int(input('Enter another district number (enter 0 to quit): '))
```

Console session:

```
Give the senators district number (enter 0 to end): 22
That district is served by the honorable Brian Birdwell.
Enter another district number (enter 0 to quit): 100
District Number too high
Enter another district number (enter 0 to quit):
```

Comment: You don't solve incorrect coding by adding try/catch blocks, you fix the code.

Comment: Thanks Games Brainiac. That really solved the riddle of the Sphinx. Now I see my error.

Comment: @FredRamirez Well if this worked for you, please upvote and accept the answer.